# React app not serving correctly with Nginx and GitHub Actions

Tags: reactjs, github, nginx, deployment, github-actions

I created a React app using **npx create-react-app** and initialized a GitHub repository for it. In order to automate deployments, I set up GitHub Actions according to the guide provided by GitHub. Additionally, I installed Nginx on my server to serve the React app build.

However, after configuring Nginx using the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file as shown below:

```
    server {
            listen 80;
            listen [::]:80;

            root /home/samuel/actions-runner/client/github-actions-example-client/github-actions-example-client/build;

            index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

            location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            }
    }
```

I encounter a 404 error page when trying to access the application.

Surprisingly, when I changed the root path to `/var/www/build` (by moving the build folder there), the application runs successfully.

I would appreciate any insights into what might be causing the issue and how I can get the React app to run in the original path (`/home/samuel/actions-runner/client/github-actions-example-client/github-actions-example-client/build`). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When facing the issue of my React app not running in the original path */home/samuel/actions-runner/client/github-actions-example-client/github-actions-example-client/build*, I found a solution within my GitHub Actions workflow file to move the build folder to the desired location (*/var/www/*) using the sudo command.

However, it's important to note that providing the user password as plain text within the workflow is not considered the most secure approach. To address this, I utilized **GitHub Secrets** to securely store and access sensitive information like passwords.

Here's how I modified my workflow file to move the build folder using the sudo command:

```
    run: echo "${{ secrets.USER_PASSWORD }}" | sudo -S rm -R /var/www/build

    run: echo "${{ secrets.USER_PASSWORD }}" | sudo -S mv /home/samuel/actions-runner/client/github-actions-example-client/github-actions-example-client/build /var/www
```

In this example, I stored my user password as a secret named **USER_PASSWORD** in the GitHub repository's Secrets settings.